# Spring cloud stream kafka setting ssl properties programmatically

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.ssl.truststore.location=/Users/truststore.jks
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.ssl.keystore.location=/Users/keystore.jks
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.ssl.truststore.password=**
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.ssl.keystore.password=**
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.ssl.key.password=**
```

I am able to connect to my secure kafka cluster using above configs but i need to programmatically connect via creating bean?

Comment: What exactly do you mean "programmatically connect"? You could set the values from the terminal if you'd rather not have passwords written in the plaintext within your source code, by the way - https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_using_spring_boot_properties

Comment: As in connect via creating bean 
``` @Bean
    @Primary
    public KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties kafkaBinderConfigurationProperties(KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties properties) {
      //
    }
Tried this not working!
Set binder properties via code!

Comment: I wanted to use vault, hence wanted a way to integrate vault via setting these props as code!

Comment: Why not do it at execution time in the shell like `java jar ... --spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.ssl.keystore.password=$(vault read -field ...)`. Then you don't need any Java Vault dependencies